# PHP 5.6 regex unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have come across a strange behaviour in PHP 5.6 (not tested with other versions)

```
var_dump(preg_match('#\b(39||90)\b#', '42')); // int(1)
var_dump(preg_match('#\b(39||90)\b#', '')); // int(0)
```

https://regex101.com says the pattern `\b(39||90)\b` is invalid but PHP preg_match does not return FALSE as it should if the pattern is invalid.

As you can see `42` produces a match and the empty string produces a non-match. I'd expect the other way round as `||` should stand for empty string.

What's happening here?

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like I get the same result on PHP 7.2.5

Comment: The empty string contains no word boundaries: *"A word boundary is a position in the subject string where the current character and the previous character do not both match `\w` or `\W` (i.e. one matches `\w` and the other matches `\W`), or the start or end of the string if the first or last character matches `\w`, respectively."* – [pcre.org/pcre.txt](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt)

Comment: I think that it's a valid pattern _technically_, it's just that regex101 doesn't like it because it figures that it's not what was intended. The error that it gives reads more like a warning ("An alternator at this position effectively truncates the group, rendering any other tokens beyond this point useless"). As for why it matches as it does, [salathe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534707/php-5-6-regex-unexpected-behaviour#comment88081555_50534707) and [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50534783/899126) have you covered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex:

```
\b(39||90)\b
```

Will return a successful match if any of the alternation is matched. These are:

1. Complete word `39`
2. Complete word `90`
3. A word boundary **anywhere** in the input (because of empty `||`)

However in empty string there is no word boundary. A word boundary `\b` is asserted true between a word `\w` and a non-word `\W`.

E.g. see these results:

```
// no word character hence false
var_dump(preg_match('#\b(39||90)\b#', '#@'));
int(0)

# a word char hence true
php > var_dump(preg_match('#\b(39||90)\b#', 'a'));
int(1)

// no word character hence false
php > var_dump(preg_match('#\b(39||90)\b#', "\t\n"));
int(0)
```

Comment: And the error message given on regex101 isn't about an invalid pattern, it's about the second | effectively truncating the group: `| An alternator at this position effectively truncates the group, rendering any other tokens beyond this point useless` meaning that anything after the second `|` is left out when parsing).

Comment: The question asks why regex101 says that the pattern is an error while PHP doesn't complain. Explaining why that is highly relevant to the question.

Comment: The `||` is a side effect or call it a bug in the application whereby a valid pattern containing a character class definition (e.g. `...|[4-8][0-9]|...`) is getting replaced with `||`. That's OK because it can be fixed. The result before fixing is still curious.

Comment: @MatsLindh I don't care what regex101 says. I want to understand PHP behaviour.

Comment: @marekful You explicitly said "as it should if the pattern is invalid". The explanation is that it's not invalid, just that it doesn't do what you think it does. This answer tells you why. `||` doesn't stand for an empty string, it causes the rest of the pattern to be ignored. Using `|()|` will allow null (no characters) to match as well, as long as it's between word boundaries.

Comment: @matsLindh If what you say is correct `var_dump(preg_match('#\b(39||90)\b#', '90'));` shouldn't produce a match but it does.

Comment: @marekful Because the pattern `#\b(39|)\b#` matches "anything between two word boundaries". You're getting a match for the start of the string and the end of the string - if you replace `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`, you'll get `2` returned.

Comment: @marekful: It will return true if there is **any** word character in input.

Comment: @marekful Remove boundaries and test result `var_dump(preg_match('#(39||90)#', ''));`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarifications. I did use empty string in meaningful regex patterns in the past but always as a last part of an or'ed expression like `(a|b|)`. What confused me is the different behaviour of the engine when it it's in the middle.